# Python not recognizing import module

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to `import urllib.parse` module, alas unsuccessfully.

I have installed Python 2.7 and 3.6 on my MacOS, which should be enough, however, when launching `python3 url.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "url.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.parse, urllib.request
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'; 'http' is not a package
```

**url.py**

```
import urllib.parse, urllib.request
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen("http://someurl.com")
```

Comment: Mmmmmh, maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880147/import-http-client-encouter-import-error-with-python-3-4-1 ?

Comment: @smagnan Yes, and I just found this question also. :) Thanks