# scrapy crawl using batch file on windows 10 no module named http.client error

Tags: python, batch-file, scrapy

I am currently manually running a few spiders (not all spiders in the project) in my scrapy project every day. Usually there are some failed pages (200 status but somehow the pages did not load properly or something) and re-run on the failed pages once or twice works. Due to this check, I would like to run a batch file on my windows 10 locally and probably use task scheduler to run it. I wrote the batch file after reading some posts but it threw an error "no module named http.client". My spiders run correctly manually and I can also get my other python script to run via batch file without problems.

The error occurs when C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\urllib\request.py trying to import http.client. There is a screenshot of the full error code.

I added C:\MyPythonScripts\ to my system path.

```
call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
cd "C:\MyPythonScripts\ScrapyProjects\myproject"
call py.exe "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\scrapy-2.3.0-py37hc8dfbb8_0\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py" crawl myspider -o myspider.csv
```

I also tried "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py" which gave the same error.

[image]

Comment: Did you perhaps find this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880147/import-http-client-encouter-import-error-with-python-3-4-1/24880220) when you searched?

Comment: @Squashman, I am not sure if it is the same issue. I did not create another file called http.py. I checked the scrapy folder, it has http.py under core\downloader\handler and another http.py under utils\ but I cannot change the library. the error occurs when C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\urllib\request.py trying to import http.client